# Can multiple Headers middlewares be combined?

Tags: http-headers, traefik

I have couple of services that require different **Content-Security-Policy** header. My initial attempt was to create a default middleware that will handle all common headers, and then I can create new middlewares with unique `contentSecurityPolicy` setting for each of the routers.

I was surprised when it turned out that if you have multiple middlewares with headers, the last applied one overwrites the previous. This means I have to recreate all the headers in the middleware for each service. And if I make changes in the future, I would have to make sure this is reflected in all of them.

As a workaround I tried to add `customResponseHeaders` with **Content-Security-Policy** header, but this did not overwrote the default header, even though it showed in the dashboard.

Excerpt of my setup:

```
...
[http.routers.service]
  rule = "Host(`example.com`)"
  entrypoints = ["https"]
  middlewares = ["default", "service"]
  service = "service"
...
[http.middlewares.default.headers]
  accessControlAllowOrigin = "origin-list-or-null"
  stsSeconds = 315360000
  stsIncludeSubdomains = true
  stsPreload = true
  customFrameOptionsValue = "SAMEORIGIN"
  contentTypeNosniff = true
  browserXssFilter = true
  referrerPolicy = "strict-origin"
  contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'none';form-action 'none';frame-ancestors 'none';base-uri 'none'"
  featurePolicy = "notifications 'none'; camera 'none'"
[http.middlewares.service.headers]
  contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'none';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';style-src 'self';img-src 'self'"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my discussion at the [Traefik forums](https://community.containo.us/t/overwrite-specific-header-only/2006), I was pointed at the fact that this seems to be expected behavior for [the used library](https://github.com/unrolled/secure). After some experimentation, I came up with this solution:

Skip the default security headers and only use the `customResponseHeaders` option. They seem to be handled separately from the mentioned library, and can be merged so you have to start with the most specific first, and then add the general ones, like this: `middlewares = ["service", "default"]`

And here is the refactored headers from the question:

```
[http.middlewares.default.headers.customResponseHeaders]
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "null"
  Content-Security-Policy = "default-src 'none';form-action 'none';frame-ancestors 'none';base-uri 'none'"
  Feature-Policy = "notifications 'none'; camera 'none'"
  Referrer-Policy = "strict-origin"
  Server = "home.stoinov.com"
  Strict-Transport-Security = "max-age=315360000; includeSubDomains; preload"
  X-Content-Type-Options = "nosniff"
  X-Frame-Options = "SAMEORIGIN"
  X-Xss-Protection = "1; mode=block"
[http.middlewares.service.headers.customResponseHeaders]
  Content-Security-Policy = "default-src 'none';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';style-src 'self';img-src 'self'"
```

The default setup is actually one line shorter than using the predefined headers for the same result.

One drawback is, that on the dashboard, you will see your headers bunched up on the top of the middleware card, but the actual security headers will be left with their default values. Which to be honest might've been a plus, if we had the header name along with the value.